# Why use "chevron right/left" icon instead "greater or less than" symbol

Tags: ux-field

What is the accessibility or usability rationale for using external/third party icons to represent    direction ? For example "chevron-right/left" from fontawesome.

Why not just use "greater or less than" characters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a considerable amount of ambiguity as to [what a right-pointing chevron means](https://uxmag.com/articles/everybody-does-right-wrong), and the same applies to a right-pointing equilateral triangle ▶. It can mean `PLAY`, `GO TO PAGE`, and more. The right-pointing chevron  can mean `OPEN MENU`, `BREADCRUMB`, and more. You also need to be careful with the double chevron **»**, which generally means `FAST-FORWARD`.

If you used a simple greater than **>** symbol, you are potentially adding a further level of ambiguity.

The reason may also be that the right-pointing chevron is more aesthetically pleasing and less pixelly, depending on the font. That is certainly true of the font-awesome offering.

It's also a [really good idea to add text to icons, or at least a tooltip, so that users know what the icon will do, as otherwise it reduces comprehension](https://www.usertesting.com/blog/user-friendly-ui-icons/).

Also, in case you're interested, I find [this site](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/) really useful for discovering unicode characters: [&what;](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/)